# Changing the player limit for a team

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

Is there a way, using the console, to force limit only one player for a team?

I am setting up a private Hide and Seek server and I want to have the Seekers (Counter-Terrorists) to have a maximum of one person and the Hiders (Terrorist) contain the rest of the players?

Also, I want to to when I use `mp_scrambleteams`, the game will auto choose a person to be a seeker, is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible via the command line. One team can just have 1/2 (50%) of servers max-player per team. You could (yep its dumb) buy e.g. 48slots, limit one team to 1 player on the other team it would a maximum of 24players then. However who wanna pay 48 slots if you can use just 25?

The only way to make it possible is to use (or write your own) server mod(s) like [**sourcemod**](https://www.sourcemod.net/) with [**this plugin**](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=219812).

Comment: Thank you, i do have sourcemod installed so i'll just use that